# get count(*) from multiple tables sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

*entry*

```
ID   title
1    Entry1
2    Entry2
3    Entry3
4    Entry4
```

*user_likes*

```
ID   user_id    entry_id
1       1           3
2       3           1
3       9           4
4       2           2
```

*user_bookmarks*

```
ID   user_id    entry_id
1       6           3
2       4           3
3       2           1
4       2           2
```

What i want is the sum of likes and bookmarks for each entry.

*result*

```
entryID   likes    bookmarks
   1        1          1
   2        1          1
   3        1          2
   4        1          0
```

Also with total sum of likes and bookmarks of each entry.

*result2*

```
entryID   likes+bookmarks
   1            2
   2            2
   3            3
   4            1
```

I managed to get likes and bookmark result using this query in seperate tables. I was not able to show them together in a single table.

```
SELECT entry.id, COUNT(entry.id) AS likes FROM entry 
INNER JOIN user_like ON user_like.entry_id = entry.id GROUP BY entry.id ORDER BY likes DESC
```

Comment: You should edit your question and show what you have attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should aggregate *before* joining:

```
select e.*, coalesce(l.likes, 0) as likes,
       coalesce(b.bookmarks, 0) as bookmarks,
       (coalesce(l.likes, 0) + coalesce(b.bookmarks, 0)) as both
from entries e left join
     (select entryid, count(*) as likes
      from likes l
      group by entryid
     ) l
     on l.entryid = e.id left join
     (select entryid, count(*) as bookmarks
      from bookmarks
      group by entryid
     ) b
     on b.entryid = e.id;
```